# Search In claims

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, ravendb

I am trying to filter users depending on the value of a specific claim.

I use ASP .Net Core 3 and RavenDB.

```
filteredData = data.Search(d => d.Email, model.search.value)
                   .Search(d => d.LastName, model.search.value)
                   .Search(d => d.FirstName, model.search.value)
                   .Search(d => d.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClaimType == "Role"), model.search.value);
```

This does not work. Here is the error message :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot understand how to translate d.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => (c.ClaimType == "Role"))'
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: Could you please tell me what is data's type? Do you use identity or other authentication schema?  Do you mean you want to get the user Email, firstname,lastname when the user's claims claim type is role?

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `Search` with `Where`.

```
filteredData = data.Search(d => d.Email, model.search.value)
                   .Search(d => d.LastName, model.search.value)
                   .Search(d => d.FirstName, model.search.value)
                   .Where(d => d.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClaimType == "Role"));
```